# Dynamic Menu from folders

Tags: menu, autohotkey

In my program I want to create a menu with submenus based on a folder and its subfolders.

The first function `menu_fromfiles` works fine.

But the second function `menu_fromfolders` keeps giving me an error: `submenu does not exist` - and I can't figure it out.  Any clues?

Here is my code:

```
 #SingleInstance force

RButton::
menu_fromfolders("filelist", "File List", "c:\test", "*.txt", "thismenu")
menu, thismenu, show

Return
-------------------------------------------------------------------


menu_fromfolders(submenuname, menutitle, whatdir, filemask="*", parentmenu="", whatsub="DONOTATHING"){
    global
        loop, %whatdir%\*, 1, 0
        {
            if(file_isfolder(A_LoopFileFullPath)){
                menu_fromfiles(a_loopfilename, a_loopfilename, A_LoopFileFullPath, filemask, "", whatsub)
                menu, %submenuname%, add, %a_loopfilename%, :%a_loopfilename%
            }else{
                menu, %submenuname%, add, %a_loopfilename%, %whatsub%
            }
        }
        if(parentmenu){
            menu, %parentmenu%, add, %menutitle%, :%submenuname%
        }       
        return submenuname
}


menu_fromfiles(submenuname, menutitle, whatdir, filemask="*", parentmenu="", whatsub="DONOTATHING"){
        loop, %whatdir%\%filemask%, 0, 0
        {
            menu, %submenuname%, add, %a_loopfilename%, %whatsub%
        }
        if(parentmenu){
            menu, %parentmenu%, add, %menutitle%, :%submenuname%
        }
        return submenuname
}


;returns true if the item is a folder, false if is a file
file_isfolder(whatfile){
    lastchar := substr(whatfile, 0, 1) ;fetch the last character from the string
    if(lastchar != "\")
        whatfile := whatfile . "\"
    if(fileexist(whatfile))
        return true
}


;empty command for the menu title
DONOTATHING:
return
```

Here is a more detailed error message:

```
Error in ...script.ahk
Submenu does not exist

-->menu, %submenuname%, add, %a_loopfilename%, :%a_loopfilename%
```

**[update]**

Please see my solution below.  You can find the complete and refined script here: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/95219-dynamicfilemenuahk/

Comment: Please post a more detailed error message. Post a sscce. You are missing the function `file_exist(whatdir)`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added both of what you requested.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: write an example that reproduces the error, but is as small as possible.

Comment: Okay, this should work if you paste it into a script file - there are no more dependencies.

Comment: I've gone over it quickly, i think your handlers,submenus.. are mixed up/missing.

Comment: Thanks for looking.  I've tried different combinations and can't get it to work.  The error is only in the two lines just below `if(file_isfolder(A_LoopFileFullPath)){`  - if I comment them out, the menu_fromfolder function will at least display the files.  I just can't get it to create the submenus from the folders.  I've already spent hours.

Comment: Are you aware that `lastchar := substr(whatfile, 1, 1)` extracts not the last, but the **first** character? I don't quite get what you're doing at that point.

Comment: Well, I had it all wrapped up in another function, and in my haste to simply things for this post, I miscoded it.  It's supposed to test the last character for a slash.  I fixed it.

Comment: Your code actually works on my machine. It shows every dir, subdir and file without an error.

Comment: Strange! It works for me too as long as I don't parse the folder that contains my script includes.

Comment: Actually, it works on some folders and not on others; I can't figure it out.

Comment: Look for differences between the working and the non-working ones, I bet there's a pattern. Maybe it has something to do with illegal chars / special chars.

Comment: The submenu names are taken from the folder names themselves.  How can an illegal character be gotten from the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, figured it out.

When the `menu_fromfiles` loop searches for files, if no files matching the mask are discovered, it does not add anything to the menu.

Now, you can't create a submenu with nothing in it. So if no items were added to the submenu, no submenu is created.

It was working intermittently only for directories that had folders containing files matching the mask.  When there were no matching files (or the directory was empty), the function was trying to add a non-existent menu.

The solution is to add a method of detecting that a menuitem was, indeed created:

```
menu_fromfiles(submenuname, menutitle, whatdir, filemask="*", parentmenu="", whatsub="DONOTATHING"){
        menucount := 0
        loop, %whatdir%\%filemask%, 0, 0
        {
            menu, %submenuname%, add, %a_loopfilename%, %whatsub%
            menucount++
        }
        if(parentmenu && menucount){
            menu, %parentmenu%, add, %menutitle%, :%submenuname%
        }
        return submenuname
}
```

If anyone is interested, I refined this code to display all the folders.  You will find the full script here: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/95219-dynamicfilemenuahk/